# Problem redirecting after creating user in backend

Tags: angular, typescript

I execute this method in order to save an user in **form-registrar-usuario.component**:

```
  registrarUsuario(){
    const role = this.route.snapshot.params["role"]
    if(role == "Proponedor"){
      this.autorizacionService.registrarUsuario(
        role,
        this.valoresForm.value.username,
        this.valoresForm.value.email,
        this.valoresForm.value.password,
        this.valoresForm.value.password2,
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "" 
        ).subscribe(
          response => {
            console.log("me voy al mainprop");
            this.router.navigate(["/mainprop/"]);
          },
          error=>{
            console.log(error);
            this.errorentrada=error;
          });
    }

  }
```

It calls to registrarUsuario from **AutorizacionService**

```
  registrarUsuario(role:string, username:string, email: string, password:string, password2:string, first_name:string, last_name:string, second_last_name:string, phone_number:string){
    //todo

    return this.http.post(
      environment.apiURL.concat('registrarusuario/'),
      {role, username, email, password, password2, first_name, last_name, second_last_name, phone_number}
    ).pipe(
      tap(response=>this.setSession(response)),
      shareReplay()
    );
  
  }
```

In the AutorizacionService method, I call to setSession to save the token and user

```
  private setSession(authResult){
    let token = authResult.token;
    let payload = <JWTPayload> jwt_decode(token);
    const expiresAt = moment.unix(payload.exp);
    localStorage.setItem('token', authResult.token);
    localStorage.setItem('expires_at', JSON.stringify(expiresAt.valueOf()));
    localStorage.setItem('user', authResult.user);
    //this.usuarioService.obtenUsuario(payload.user_id).subscribe((usuarioRetornado:Usuario) => localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(usuarioRetornado)) );
  }
```

I can save the user with this in the DB, but the first method never redirect to mainprop.  **app-routing-module**:

```
  { path: "mainprop", component: PrincipalProponedorDeSubrutinasComponent, canActivate:[SesionIniciada, EsUsuarioProponedorDeSubrutinas]},
```

These are SesionIniciada and EsUsuarioProponedorDeSubrutinas

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EsUsuarioProponedorDeSubrutinas implements CanActivate{
  constructor(
    private autorizacionService: AutorizacionService,
    ) { }
    canActivate(): boolean {
      return this.autorizacionService.obtenUsuarioSesion()["role"]=="Proponedor";
    }

}


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SesionIniciada implements CanActivate{
  constructor(
    private autorizacionService: AutorizacionService,
    ) { }
    canActivate(): boolean {
      return this.autorizacionService.isLoggedIn();
    }

}
```

The problem is that obtenUsuarioSesion, called from canActivate, can't obtain the user from the localStorage, and stay infinitely in the while loop. but user from localStorage was stored before I think.

```
  obtenUsuarioSesion():Usuario{
    //localStorage.clear();
    //return null;
    console.log("entro al bucle");
    while(localStorage.getItem('user')=="undefined"){}
    console.log("salgo del bucle: ", localStorage.getItem('user'));
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if a key doesn't exist in the localStorage, then localStorage.getItem() will return null (Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)

In your case, the code gets stuck at the while because the condition is true if the value associated to the localStorage key 'user' is equal to 'undefined' string

You can try to change the condition to:

```js
while(localStorage.getItem('user') === null){}
```

Although I don't think having the while loop is necessary, because theoretically when the guard is run the localStorage should already contain the user